# How to persist authentification data in Vue JS when consuming my own Laravel API

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, api, vue.js

I am new to Front End development and I am trying to understand what are the good practices in term of front end authentification.

In my situation I have a Laravel API consumed by my own Vue JS Single Page Application. There is a login page targeting a **/login** web route. The rest of the app is using api route to get api resources.

Of course I followed the step in the official Laravel documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/passport#consuming-your-api-with-javascript

So as expected the CreateFreshApiToken middleware create the *laravel-token* cookie and authentification is working.

BUT my concern is about the client side. I read a lot of articles / examples about how to handle authentification in front end app. And all of them are storing a JWT token in the local storage, and then using Vuex they map this JWT token with a "loggedIn" state.
In my scenario the JWT token is passed in the *laravel-token* cookie. This cookie is httpOnly, so I cannot read it, and I can't even check the existence of it.

So my question is: In this case, using the laravel-token cookie and the CreateFreshApiToken middleware, what is the best practice to check if a user is logged in and persist the state after page reload ?

Comment: Why do you need to read that token with your frontend? Your state is persisted, you've got a cookie with token inside it - there's nothing for you to do, browser automatically delivers cookies when performing requests to the domain that set the cookie.

Comment: The front end is Single Page Application ( I forgot to precise that sorry ), and it needs to make sure the user is logged in and the token is still valid before each change is made. From what I understand and because of the SPA behavior, the back end is not called on every change, so the front end has to handle a part of the authentification process and verification. Am I correct ?

Comment: So.. why would it need to make sure user is logged in? You lost me there.. if user logs in, he/she gets served the SPA. Token is in the cookie. Each XHR is authenticated/authorized because cookie is sent with every request. If expired, 401 or 403 is served, do the login process again. Frontend has to do literally nothing there, it kind of defeats the purpose, doesn't it? You want your frontend to works if user gets authenticated and if that happens - you want to stop worrying about authentication.

Comment: Well lets say the cookie expired after 1 hour. Because it is a SPA, the user can do a lots of actions without any XHR request to the back end. When I said " make sure the user is logged in" , I meant, making sure the laravel-token is still valid. If not, the user has to be logged out, and has to sign in again.

Comment: So if you had the info *when* the cookie expires, what would you do with that info? You could simply add an interceptor that checks if status code received from laravel is 401 or 403 and show the login form in modal window - without losing any work within SPA and perform the login again.